# phpredis debug method not working

Tags: redis, phpredis

i recently updated php redis version to 3.0.0-rc1 after that
$data = $redis->debug('Key');
var_dump($data); gives output bool(false)
is debug method disabled or need to do anything to make that method work

Comment: I searched the code on GitHub and it doesn't appear like there is a `debug` method. Are you saying this did work before upgrading? Also, can you be specific on where you are getting PHPredis from? The git hub version just moved from 2.4-2.7 10 days ago. Perhaps I am looking at the wrong code?

Comment: @varlogtim, thanks for the reply yes it worked for me [link](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/342)

https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/commit/96374a91051ded6275885dd2459f0c7bd5d300fe

https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/releases

Comment: I am wondering if something else is causing the issue. Are you able to make other method calls in your current code, aside form the debug method? Perhaps the `$redis` object isn't being instantiated correctly, such as from an include problem due to the upgade?

Comment: OK, I do see a debug method currently in there. However, I am wondering if the response back is just `false` - What happens when you call other methods?

Comment: @varlogtim other method were working fine give proper responses, methods like scan, hget, hgetall, set, hmset all working fine

Comment: What I mean is that you are not getting an error, just a false response. I do not have experience with this, I am just trying to help troubleshoot. I would look at potential issues that could have occurred with upgrading. Just basic stuff like, do other methods work. What if you use a different "Key"? Etc.. Sorry I am not more help :)

Comment: I also experience this: a) in redis-cli i DO get output of `debug object foo`
 while b) in php i get FALSE as output of `$redis->debug('foo')`

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, see [this issue report](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/943).